# Magento 2 Custom module error when changing constructor

Tags: magento-2.1, module, dependency-injection

I am creating a new custom module for Magento 2.1.x which some includes some Blocks. In one of them, at the beginning of the development, the constructor had onlt two parameters:

```
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Products extends Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Lately I had to add a new parameter to the constructor

```
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Products extends Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $productCollectionFactory);
    }
}
```

If I reload the frontend I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::__construct() must be of the
>   type array, object given, called in ...

What should I do to make the new constructor work? Should I delete something? Should I run some command via CLI? (I am using the developer mode)

Comment: Your parent constructor argument should look like this `parent::__construct($context, $data);` and if you want to get product collection on template create a function called getProductCollection or yourFunctionName and return product collection like `return $this->_productCollectionFactory` this may resolve your issue.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! It is just a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent constructor argument should look like this `parent::__construct($context, $data);` and if you want to get product collection on template create a function called getProductCollection or yourFunctionName and return product collection like `return $this->_productCollectionFactory` and call that function in template you will get collection.

You block should look like :

```
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Products extends Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    //call $this->getProductCollection() will return product collection in template file.

    public function getProductCollection(){
        return $this->_productCollectionFactory;
    }
}
```